# How can I get a list of netCDF variables with particular dimensions?

Tags: python, r, netcdf, netcdf4, nco

```
{
dimensions:
    grp = 50 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (0 currently)
    depth = 3 ;
    scalar = 1 ;
    spectral_bands = 2 ;
    x1AndTime = 13041 ;
    x2AndTime = 13041 ;
    midTotoAndTime = 13041 ;
variables:
    double time(time) ;
    double a1(time, hru) ;
    double a2(time, hru) ;
    double a3(x1AndTime, hru) ;
    double a4(x2AndTime, hru) ;
    double a5(hru) ;
```

Open the netCDF file in `R`

`out <- ncdf4::nc_open('test.nc')`

Get all the variables

`ncvars <- names(out[['var']])`

This gives me a list of *all* the variables in the netCDF file.

How can I get a list of the variables that have dimensions `time` and `hru`, for example?

Intended output:

List with `a1, a2`

Comment: I don't know R, but I could show a python solution if that might help.

Comment: @EricBridger Please do,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this is python, not R but illustrates the logic.

```
import netCDF4

out = netCDF4.Dataset("test.nc")
# list of vars w dimenions 'time' and 'hru'
wanted_vars = []

# loop thru all the variables
for v in out.variables:
  # this is the name of the variable.
  print v
  # variable.dimensions is a tuple of the dimension names for the variable
  # In R you might need just ('time', 'hru')
  if out.variables[v].dimensions == (u'time', u'hru'):
    wanted_vars.append(v)

print wanted_vars
```

Comment: Uhm, the question is about `R`?

Comment: I asked @maximusdooku if python would help.

Comment: Ah, sorry.. missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```r
nc <- ncdf4::nc_open("/some/nc/file.nc")
for (vi in seq_along(nc$var)) { # for all vars of nc file
   dimnames_of_var <- sapply(nc$var[[vi]]$dim, "[[", "name")
   message(length(nc$var[[vi]]$dim), " dims of var ", names(nc$var)[vi], ": ", 
        paste(dimnames_of_var, collapse=", "))
   if (all(!is.na(match(dimnames_of_var, c("hru", "time"))))) { # order doesnt matter
      message("variable ", names(nc$var)[vi], " has the wanted dims!")
   }
}
```